PHP redirect is not wkring as intended
I have a website where a user can log in from two different locations. I'm running into an issue when I attempt to manage the error handeling for empty input logins and invalid logins. Essentially what is happening is when either one of the error condtions are met my php script is running a redirect incorrectly. It is redirecting to https://www.website.com/www.website.com?error=emptyinput instead of https://www.website.com?error=emptyinput Any assistance in resolving this issue would be great.
Login Function
function loginUser ($username, $password, $conn){
    //require_once 'PasswordHash.php';
    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);
    if ($uidExists === false) {
        $result = false;
            $referer = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if (strpos($referer, '?') !== false) {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "&error=wrongLogin";
    } else {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "?error=wrongLogin";
    }
        header("location: ../".$errorUrl);
        exit();
    }
    $pwdHashed = $uidExists ['password'];
    $password= $_POST['pwd'];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($password, $pwdHashed);
    if ($checkPwd === false) {
                $referer = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if (strpos($referer, '?') !== false) {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "&error=wrongLogin";
    } else {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "?error=wrongLogin";
    }
        header("location: ../".$errorUrl);
        exit();
    }else if ($checkPwd === true) {
        $result = true;
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists ["id"];
            $_SESSION["useruid"] = $uidExists ["username"];
            $_SESSION["role"] = $uidExists["role"];
            $userID = $uidExists ["id"];
            if ($uidExists['resetFlag']!=0) {
                header("location: ../profile.php?resetFlag=1");
            }else{
            header("location: ../dashboard.php");
        }
            
    }
    return $result;  
}

Login.inc.php
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$username = $_POST['uid'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';
    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        if (emptyInputLogin($username, $password) !== false) {
    $referer = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if (strpos($referer, '?') !== false) {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "&error=emptyinput";
    } else {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "?error=emptyinput";
    }
        header("location: ../".$errorUrl);
        exit();
    }
        $data = $_SESSION['idata'];
        $locoData = $_SESSION['locoData'];
        uploadLogin($conn, $username, $password, $data, $locoData);
    }else{
    
    

    if (emptyInputLogin($username, $password) !== false) {
        $referer = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if (strpos($referer, '?') !== false) {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "&error=emptyinput";
    } else {
        $errorUrl = $referer . "?error=emptyinput";
    }
        header("location: ../".$errorUrl);
        exit();
    }

    loginUser($username, $password, $conn);
}
}else{
    header("location: ../login.php");
}


Because the redirection location is ../".$errorUrl --> ../".$referer . "?error=emptyinput". Have you checked its value out?

You should not use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to redirect, or any other functionality, because its value is not reliable. My guess is you use it because of the "two locations". There are alternatives, but which one you should use depends on what you're doing.

In the little bit of code, in your question, you perform the same action, of getting the referrer, checking if it contains a "?", then adding the error and redirect, four times. Why didn't you make a function for this? It would almost half the length of your code. See: Don’t repeat yourself (DRY) in Software Development.

@shingo I put vardumps before the redirect and it turns out I needed to take the ../ out of the header redirect for it to work correctly as the url was already being generated from the $errorUrl

@KIKOSoftware functions are still a big mystery for me, I use them in some locations but am completely lost on how to utilize them in other applications.

OK, I understand. Anyway, try to stay away from using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in any functionality of your code. It might work for you right now, but that's just luck.

@KIKOSoftware if you have any alternatives im open to suggestions.

I don't know what the two possible referrers would look like, making it hard to give a good suggestion. You probably should use a combination of  $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. But really, I think logging in from "two locations" is a bad idea to start with. The code should be dealing with the login, not with where the login came from.

$referer = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Try changing to
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

I wonder why you are changing HTTP_REFERER through basename function.
Why not just use HTTP_REFERER ?
basename function is used to return the file name from a file path.
For example, basename("/etc/passwd") returns passwd

try it this way
<?php 
   header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?err=someError");
  //http://localhost/test/ref.php?err=someError
?>

tahnk me later :)
